# Why are 100000 iterations of a for loop faster than 50000?

Tags: javascript, performance

I've been working on this page to graph the performance of different aspects of javascript. In the process of trying to graph a simple for loop at a varying number of iterations I've found that the speed of the loop seems to dramatically increase at some point over 50000 iterations and I am very interested to know why.

Here's the loop I'm using:

```
var oN = function (n)
{
    var startTime;
    var endTime;
    startTime = window.performance.now();
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {};
    endTime = window.performance.now() - startTime;
    return endTime.toFixed(2);
}
```

The value of test is n=1000000 in this picture
[image]

Comment: How many tests did you do?

Comment: An empty loop seems like a bad test.

Comment: You're probably right I'll try adding some code to the loop

Comment: Run the tests a couple hundred times and see how much of that is natural fluctuation.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/really-empty-loops + https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65-RbBwZQdU

Comment: I added 4 lines of code to the for loop with the same results  
        var x = i * 72;  
        var y = 100000 / i;  
        x + y;

Comment: It's probably about Just-in-time compiler warmup - at some point compiler recognizes your function as hot and optimizes it. Than later tests can start with already optimized code. Check if your results are sensitive to reversing order of tests.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by reversing the order of the tests?

Comment: @JohnPizzo Yeah, that's weird. I get the same result as you. For what it's worth, I'm using Chrome.

Comment: I meant you to run first big test and then small ones. You can also run your benchmark several times in one session and look at the differences.

Comment: Well, it's not reproducible. Neither on jsperf, not using your snippet. http://jsfiddle.net/1k363px4/

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, I'll try it

Comment: @JohnPizzo Check this out. Here's a fiddle with your test: https://jsfiddle.net/cd3Ljn0o/ But if you comment out `oN(50000)`, then `oN(100000)` suddenly takes a lot longer to run: https://jsfiddle.net/cd3Ljn0o/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cd3Ljn0o/2/ guys, your "performance tests" measure rubbish. Seriously. Either test in isolation or do not test at all - the numbers for a VM that is left in some unknown state make no sense at all.

Comment: I have to go ahead and agree with a benchmark.. Run the test multiple times and work out the average for each test. Also make sure you eliminate in any test the possibility of cache. Also make sure this is not being executed straight after dom ready or page load unless your trying to measure a websites load time/performance factors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously there are a lot of factors here, but [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/) article from Chris Wilson at Google about how Chrome's two JIT compilers work may explain *part* of what you are seeing.

In particular:

> **The Optimizing Compiler**
>
> In parallel with the full compiler, V8 re-compiles "hot" functions (**that is, functions that are run many times**) with an optimizing compiler. This compiler uses type feedback to make the compiled code faster - in fact, it uses the types taken from ICs we just talked about!
>
> In the optimizing compiler, operations get speculatively inlined (directly placed where they are called). This speeds execution (at the cost of memory footprint), but also enables other optimizations. Monomorphic functions and constructors can be inlined entirely (that's another reason why monomorphism is a good idea in V8).
>
> You can log what gets optimized using the standalone "d8" version of the V8 engine:

`d8 --trace-opt primes.js`

> (this logs names of optimized functions to stdout.)
> Not all functions can be optimized, however - some features prevent the optimizing compiler from running on a given function (a "bail-out"). In particular, **the optimizing compiler currently bails out on functions with try {} catch {} blocks!**

So you can compare your [original](https://jsfiddle.net/cd3Ljn0o/), with a [version inside try {} catch {} blocks](https://jsfiddle.net/cd3Ljn0o/3/) to prevent the optimizing compiler from interfering, and you will probably get a result closer to what you originally expected.

Answer (score 4):

It's unclear from your question whether you fully understand statistics or the scientific method, so it may be that a quick recap will be useful. Apologies if you *do* understand, it may be a misapprehension on my part, but I think it's preferable to explain anyway, since the next person reading your question may gain valuable insight even if you don't.

---

Re statistics, unless you're basing your results on a relatively large sample size, the results cannot be relied upon, *especially* when the sort of timings you're examining (on the order of <sup>1</sup>/<sub>10000<sup>th</sup></sub> of a second) can easily be swamped by a bit of "noise".

For example, you may find that the computer you're testing it on with hit by a burst of activity by a different process when running the 50K test.

There are a number of ways to mitigate this issue, such as running with a lot more loops (so that any short-duration noise will have less of an impact), or running the test a great many times, averaging the results (for the same reason).

---

Re the scientific method, it's a good idea to perform experiments only changing one variable at a time: scientists use the phrase "all other things being equal" quite a bit and for good reason.

What I'm getting at here is the possibility that your Javascript interpreter is, at some point, recognising that the code in the loop is being run a great many times and is therefore performing a JIT conversion on it.

Chrome [*does* do JIT compilation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/), containing a baseline JIT compiler which gets run on all code, and an optimising compiler which is more targeted but can produce far faster code.

To test that premise (that it's the JIT compiler), and assuming you're doing all the iteration sets in a single program run, you could reverse the order of them, or warm up the program by running a couple of 100K cycles first (throwing away the results).

Here are the results from Chrome under Windows. The code is taken from:

```
var oN = function (n)
{
    var startTime;
    var endTime;
    startTime = window.performance.now();
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {};
    endTime = window.performance.now() - startTime;
    return endTime.toFixed(2);
}

alert(oN(500000));
alert(oN(50000));
alert(oN(5000));
alert(oN(500));
```

with the order of the `alert` calls being the only thing changing. The figures were extracted from ten separate runs and averaged to produce the below results.

With the `alert` calls in ascending order, we see something similar to you:

```
   500  0.02
  5000  0.08
 50000  0.80 \
500000  0.61 / strange behaviour here
```

Putting them in descending order in the source gives a slightly different view:

```
   500  0.00
  5000  0.02
 50000  0.79
500000  2.21
```

which is seemingly much more logical.

I'd suggest running the same tests on your browser (or just reverse the order using your own test harness) to see if you have similar results.

Comment: plus 1 for a measured response to criticism.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I think you should try the same code more times. I executed your code but get normal result.Try to let `n` be a bigger number, the inaccuracy of the test will be weakened. Moreover, your vacant loop can be optimized. Please avoid making your loop nonsense. The browser is busy at the beginning of page loading, arranging doms worming up engines, etc. If you try to call this later the result maybe become normal.</del>

http://jsfiddle.net/87nt9gtg/3/

When the same code is executed the second time, the procedure will be optimized by the browser. So this time it may be slow, but will be faster in later times.

Comment: That's weird indeed. Did you see any more exceptional circumstances?

Comment: I wrote a test code which works normally on my computers: http://jsfiddle.net/87nt9gtg/

Comment: Is your code executed when the page is loaded? I think I've got an answer

Comment: The browser is busy that time, arranging doms worming up engines, etc. If you try to call this later the result maybe become normal.

Comment: @simonmysun oh god: JS and DOM run in the same thread. Gosh, how much else weird assumptions will you all do in this question? "worming up engines" --- what does it even mean?

Comment: I meant "warm up".. sorry for that.

Comment: @simonmysun so what "warming up engines" means?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616283/javascript-performance-warmup) is a similar question about proformance warming up, thought that one is quite a long time.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/87nt9gtg/3/ when you use the same code the second time, the browser will optimise it for you, so this time is slow, but will be faster later.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var oN = function (iteration, n)
{
    var startTime;
    var endTime;
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < iteration; i++) {
        startTime = window.performance.now();
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            var dummy = j * i;
        }
        sum += window.performance.now() - startTime;
    }
    return (sum / iteration).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to test a time complexity of O(n)  that is a complexity of O(n^2)

Comment: The outer loop is O(n^2). The inner loop is O(n). The clock is reset each time the outer loop completes an iteration. Thus this method tests O(n) complexity m times.